# What is the importance of R1 connected in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, triac, dimmer, diac

[image: DIMMER]

What is the importance of R1 in this circuit? What would happen if I removed R<sub>1</sub> and kept VR<sub>1</sub>?

Comment: depends on what you mean by `remove R1`

Comment: think about what VR1 is ... think about its effect on the circuit when it is adjusted to either extreme

Comment: are you able to read the component values in the schematic that you posted?

Comment: Downvoted because schematic is unreadable.

Comment: @PStechPaul: Schematic is sufficiently readable to answer the question. I don't understand the down votes.

Comment: Yes, I can figure out what is being shown, but it's not that hard to post a clear schematic. I'll give the OP an upvote if they redo the schematic.

Comment: When an image ends up like that it's because there's some transparency junk in the image. To deal with that, take a screen shot of the image and crop, or use Windows Snipping Tool.

Comment: I'm sorry for the image apearance but , I was in harry..

Answer (score 6):

If \$R_{1} = 0\ \Omega \$, and \$V\!R_{1}\$ is adjusted to \$0\ \Omega \$, then the current through the DIAC and the gate of the TRIAC would be too high, causing one or both to be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks , For your answer.. But how do I calculate the value of R1?

Answer (score 5):

R<sub>1</sub> limits the maximum current into the TRIAC gate when VR<sub>1</sub> is at 0 Ω.

Because it is only about 1% of VR, it has very little effect on the brightness adjustment range.

Answer (score 4):

R1 gives you finer control.

Suppose the ideal range of total resistance is 900-1k ohms.   You can get that control with a single 1k variable resistor, but you only would use 10% of the pots possible travel.  Suppose instead you use 900 ohm fixed resistor in series with a 100 ohm pot.  In this case, you get the whole rotation of the pots travel to make your adjustments.  I.e. you can set a value with 10x the precision.

@AnalogKid answer is right also.   Either of these (or both really) could be the reason.